# How to use Gmail, Heroku and Zerigo together

Tags: heroku, dns, gmail

I use Dynodot as my ISP. When I attempt to set a CNAME (Heroku doesn't support A names) and MX records simultaneously in the Dynodot control panel, I get a "When the Domain Record is set to CNAME, MX Records or Email Forwarding is not allowed" error.

So I'm trying to do things "the Heroku way" using Zerigo.

I've already used Zerigo on Heroku to successfully serve http://testivate.com from http://testivate.herokuapp.com. Now I need to also access Gmail at http://mail.testivate.com.

Unfortunately, the help guide on Heroku is full of detail on the stuff I've done already, and short on detail on the stuff I've not yet done:

```
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/zerigo_dns
```

Basically, it just says:

> Clicking “Configure” will automatically sign you in to the Zerigo DNS
>   management interface. In there, you have full control to manage your
>   MX Records.

However, when you are in the DNS management interface you don't see fields that look like they're meant to take MX records. You don't see anywhere obvious to put the following, for example:

```
Name/Host/Alias  Time to Live (TTL)  Record Type     Value/Answer/Destination
Blank or @           300                   MX            1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
Blank or @           300                 MX          5 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
Blank or @           300                   MX            5 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
Blank or @           300                 MX         10 ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM
Blank or @           300                   MX           10 ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM
```

What is the name of the specific tab I should be on? And the specific field in which I should enter this data? Are there any other steps? Thanks. Steven.

Postscript:

I've now managed to get this going solely through Dynadot by setting a Forward not a CNAME on the base domain, which then let me enter the MX details into the Dynadot control panel. However, I'd still be interested in knowing how to do this through Zerigo.

Answer (score 0):

If your CNAME record is for the www subdomain, you can set the MX records by not specifying a subdomain.